# passing value to blade without use of foreach

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

i am trying to fetch a single row  value using its' key in blade file table. how do it pass value to it.
i have fetched the whole table in another blade file using foreach

i have passed the data from my controller but it doesn't recognize them.

loaninterest.blade.php

```
<div class="col-md-12">   
<table class="table table-stripped">
<thead>
  <tr>   
  <th>Loan Id</th>
  <th>Member</th> 
  @for($i=0;$i<$loan->duration; $i++ )
  <th>installment</th>
  @endfor
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>{{++$key}}</td>
  <td>{{$loan->member->name}}</td>
 @for($i=0;$i<$loan->duration; $i++ )
 <td> {{$loan->interest_amount}}  </td>
 @endfor
</tr>
  </thead>
  </table>
 </form>
        </div>
```

LoanController.php

```
  public function loanInterest(){
    $loanData = Loan::all();
    //$findUser =Loan::findOrFail($criteria);
    return view($this->_pagePath.'loan.loaninterest',compact('loanData'));
}
```

web.php

```
 Route::any('loaninterest/{criteria?}','LoanController@loanInterest')-> name('loaninterest');
```

i called loaninterest blade file as below

loan.blade.php

```
   <td>
    <a href="{{route('loaninterest').'/'.$loan->id }}">Interest detail</a> 
  </td>
```

how do i pass loanData in blade. i get this error

```
Undefined variable:loan
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you pass url when you used route

```
<a href="{{route('loaninterest', $loan->id) }}">Interest detail</a> 

public function loanInterest(){
        // $loanData = Loan::all();
        $loanData =Loan::findOrFail($criteria); // or your where condition
        return view($this->_pagePath.'loan.loaninterest',compact('loanData'));
}
```

In controller you are querying all data from table but you want only one data so you have to do `findOrFail` with unique id or use `firstOrFail`.

Try with this.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: i have made change u suggested in loan.blade.php, i used route since i passed values through controller function. error is same.

Comment: yes i made changed it but i still need to call it from blade file right?? like {{$loanData }} or something like that. error is same.

Comment: you just have to call only your data columns like `{{ $loanData->something }}`

Comment: it worked thank you. i was just copying codes and screwed up.

Answer (score 1):

Route parameters are send in a separate array try below code
Syntax is

```
  route('routename', [parameter1, paramater2])
```

check [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/urls#urls-for-named-routes)

you can try

```
<a href="{{route('loaninterest', ['load' => $loan->id]) }}">Interest detail</a>
```

for displaying loan data in view

```
 public function loanInterest(){
    $loanData = Loan::all();
    return view($this->_pagePath.'loan.loaninterest', compact('loanData')); //verify if $this->pagePath etc is correct
}
```

In view

```
@foreach ( $loanData as $loanDeta )
    {{ $lanData->interest_amount }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: is it required to call it from blade file similar to @foreach($loanData as $key while fetching all data

Comment: @PrithviTuladhar for creating paramterise route url this is the code, for collection traversing, yes you can use `@foreach` or `@for` blade tags, based on your requirement. you may like to upvote it if it is helpful to you.

Comment: i  guess this will give interest of all loans. that is why i didn't used @foreach at the first place. thanks anyway i caught my error.